CMake : get_target_property called on non-existent target "xyz"
This is a C/C++ project. I want to exclude a particular compilation target (say "xyz") from my setup. There are macros already in place for that (say, XYZ), which I have successfully set to OFF so that the sources are not included.
Now the CMake setup is not from me, and I am fairly new to CMake. But what I see now is :

get_target_property called on non-existent target "xyz"
get_target_property called on non-existent target "xyz"
Cannot specify compile options for target "xyz" which is not built by this

The main CMakeLists has this :
if(XYZ)
   add_subdirectory(xyz)
   target_link_libraries(main INTERFACE xyz)
endif()

This successfully does not get called. Then some CMakeList down the directory hierarchy (in the env folder) has this :
find_package(CorePackage CONFIG REQUIRED)
include(${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/targetCompileOptions.cmake)

targetCompileOptions()

The code for this last function is found elsewhere :

function(targetCompileOptions)
    set(compileOptions -Werror=double-promotion
                       -Werror=incompatible-pointer-types
                       ...
        )

    set(uniqueTargets "")
    set(parsedTargets "")

    macro(getAllNotInterfaceLibs targets)
        foreach(target ${targets})
            if(${target} IN_LIST uniqueTargets OR ${target} IN_LIST parsedTargets)
                continue()
            endif()
            list(APPEND parsedTargets ${target})
            if (NOT ${target} STREQUAL "tar-NOTFOUND")
                get_target_property(type ${target} TYPE)
                if (NOT ${type} STREQUAL "INTERFACE_LIBRARY")
                    list(APPEND uniqueTargets ${target})
                    get_target_property(tar ${target} LINK_LIBRARIES)
                    getAllNotInterfaceLibs("${tar}")
                else()
                    get_target_property(tar ${target} INTERFACE_LINK_LIBRARIES)
                    getAllNotInterfaceLibs("${tar}")
                endif()
            endif()
        endforeach()
    endmacro()

    getAllNotInterfaceLibs(main)

    list(REMOVE_DUPLICATES uniqueTargets)

    foreach(target ${uniqueTargets})
        target_compile_options(${target} PRIVATE ${compileOptions})
    endforeach()

endfunction()

So this function seems to take a target, get list of linked targets, remove duplicates, and on whatever targets remain, apply some compilation options that we like.
The error is given at the call to the targetCompileOptions function in the env CMakeLists.
Should I look in my code for a place where it still (and wrongly, now that I have it deactivated) references "xyz" and links it to the main target ? What are ways that "xyz" could still be referenced & linked, aside from target_link_libraries ? Is there something I don't understand ?

target_compile_options(${target} PRIVATE ${compileOptions}) What is the point of the function? Why not just add compile options globally and be done with it?

I think the function tries to do just that. Did you have any other mechanism in mind ?

for adding compile options to all targets? just add_compile_options().

This is beyond my knowledge here. Care to expand, especially on the difference, and pros and cons ?

What do you mean? add_compile_options() adds compile options for all targets that follow. target_compile_options adds compile options for one target. I do not know what are pros and cons, both functions do something slightly different. If you want to add compile options for all targets, might be simpler to just add_compile_options. I do not know if that is related to your question (I do not understand the question).

Ah I see, yeah it does clarify things. You say "all targets that follow", what does that exactly encompass ? Targets that are linked against this one but not targets that link against this one ? In some oriented dependency sense ?

All targets that are defined below add_compile_options() in the CMakeLists.txt file including targets defined in add_subdirectory below add_compile_options() in the CMakeLists.txt file.

Oh, "below" as in literally in the subsequent lines of code, treating add_subdirectory as a code include ?

Yes. It's like, it sets a (directory-) global variable, and then defining a target uses that (directory-)global variable. See documentation.

target_link_libraries(otherStuff PUBLIC xyz) was discovered elsewhere, and otherStuff is itself linked to main. Wether this is necessary remains to be seen.
